# Octobercms: how to localize path?

Tags: localization, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I have a multilingual website. The localization plugin seems to translate only the content, but leaves a path in the default language. How do I change a path to the selected language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the Translate Extended plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/excodus-translateextended

This plugin can prefix all routes with SEO-friendly locale short code like :

- mysite.ch/fr/contact
- mysite.ch/de/kontact

Comment: Aww, thanks. I was not aware of those features of Translate extended plugin.